# Angular 2+: control of visibility

Tags: angular, model-view-controller

I like to control the visibility of some content with a button (click it to show the content).
The best I can think is to control it with a boolean variable.

```
<button (click)="show=true">ShowIt</button>
<div *ngIf="show == true">{{ content }}</div>

show : boolean = false;
content : string = "blablabla"
```

I think thats pretty clumsy. Is there a more elegant way?

**EDIT**

It is not about how to hide something. It is more about if I really need an extra variable for that.

Comment: This is the recommended way instead of using `[hidden]`. On a sidenote, this questions is of the opinionated type and doesn't really belong on SO.

Answer (score 1):

I think using `*ngIf` is totally fine. You could e.g. implement a toggle with:

```
<button (click)="show = !show">Toggle content</button>
<div *ngIf="show">{{content}}</div>
```

From the [docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf):

> The most common usage of the ngIf directive is to conditionally show
>   the inline template as seen in this example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ng-if-simple',
  template: `
    <button (click)="show = !show">{{show ? 'hide' : 'show'}}</button>
    show = {{show}}
    <br>
    <div *ngIf="show">Text to show</div>
`
})
class NgIfSimple {
  show: boolean = true;
}
```

Looks like your stuff.